# Android Studio can't find neither physical device or AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-18.04

I'm using android studio 4.0 and everything was working fine but this time when I opened android studio I realized that android studio can't find devices:

[image]

I opened the AVD manager and I can still see the emulator exists and when  I tried to start it,  it started but with this message:

[image]

But the android studio still couldn't find any device. when I run  `adb devices` the emulator is listed!.
The same went for physical devices.
this is my SDK tools:
[image]

Here it's what I tried to do:

- delete the emulator and recreated it.
- delete the android studio settings folder.
- use a different version of android studio.

Comment: have you updated your PATH variable as indicated in the docs? can run the adb command in your terminal?

Comment: @moghwan the command line and the path are fine

Comment: Have you tried to reboot your computer? Sometimes the "debug certification" for the physical device is revoked. You can try to remove all the certifications, on device, in the developer settings page and redo the "approve debug certification". But this is only for the physical device. I've seen this bug multiple times.

Comment: THX @HarounHajem, but I think this's the case here since the Android Studio can't find the Emulator too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by going to `home/'computerName'/Android/Sdk` and delete the `platform-tools` folder and then reinstall it.

Comment: I had mistakenly deleted my `home/'computerName'/Android/Sdk` folder. Restoring it worked.